# Drawing a contour plot (meshc) with black lines

Tags: octave, figure

When using Octave's `mesh` function, the color of the lines can be set with `edgecolor`. But this property isn't available when you create a contour plot with `meshc`.

Is there any easy way to set the lines of a contour plot to a constant color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meshc` plots a contour graph under a mesh graph. Use `h=meshc(...)` to get the handle `h` to  the mesh (`h(1)`) and the contour plot (`h(2)`).
Now to change the color of the lines, the relevant property for `mesh` is `EdgeColor` while for the contour plot, it is `LineColor`. So you need to modify these properties to get the desired output.

**Example:**

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:.125:3);
Z = peaks(X,Y);
h=meshc(Z);
set(h(1),'EdgeColor','k');
set(h(2),'LineColor','k');
```

which gives:

[image: output]